# node: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND (localhost:5000) running on different localhost:8888

Tags: javascript, node.js, tradingview-api

So I have this code sample below.

```
var newUrl = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5000,
    path: '/histo',
    // method: 'GET'
}

var newestUrl = JSON.stringify(newUrl)

console.log("newestUrl " + newestUrl)

httpGet(newestUrl, address, function (result) {
    if (response.finished) {
        // we can be here if error happened on socket disconnect
        return;
    }

    if (result.status !== 'ok') {
        if (result.status === 'ERR_SOCKET') {
            console.log('Socket problem with request: ' + result.errmsg);
            sendError("Socket problem with request " + result.errmsg, response);
            return;
        }

        console.error(dateForLogs() + "Error response from quandl for key " + key + ". Message: " + result.errmsg);
        markQuandlKeyAsInvalid(quandlKey);
        sendError("Error quandl response " + result.errmsg, response);
        return;
    }
```

this code was running in localhost with port 8888 
[image]
and I need to pass some json from the API i have, localhost:5000/histo, which is where the getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND error coming from.

I already added 127.0.0.1 localhost from the etc\host (I dont know if updating this file requires restarting the PC to take effect, but I haven't done it anyway)
I already googled a lot about this kind of error but won't work.

Comment: this is the error that shows: 
{"s":"error","errmsg":"Socket problem with request getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND {"host":"localhost","port":5000,"path":"/histo"} {"host":"localhost","port":5000,"path":"/histo"}:443"}

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send request to some address you need to have server running on this address. Make sure both localhost:8888 and localhost:5000 operational at the moment you sending request.

/etc/hosts you need to edit when you have some problems with name resolution, not ip. Suppose you running some localhost:3656 and want to makre request on it as example.com, then you have to add line to /etc/hosts to explain that example.com need to be resovled as localhost:3656

Comment: thanks for the answer. yes, i made sure both are working/running in the first place.

Comment: Can you then execute request with curl and post output please?

Comment: localhost:5000/histo  -- i run this in the browser and returns like this
[{"_id":"5dd4d44e2913e950da36788d","ticker":"AAPL","date":"2018-03-23","open":"177.3168.39","high":"177.4169.92","low":"173.66,164.94","close":"175.164.94","volume":"328040248954.0","ex-dividend":"0.0","split_ratio":"1.0","adj_open":"17168.39","adj_high":"17169.92","adj_low":"173164.94","adj_close":"1164.94","adj_volume":"40248954.0"}]

Comment: I noticed you stringify newUrl, are you sure that is needed?
{"host":"localhost","port":5000,"path":"/histo"}:443 - that somehow looks for me as that stringified value, as url, then colon and port 443, which is used for ssl connection, and which you not have running on localhost, I think.

Comment: Well even if you have have something on 443 running, still that stringified json is hardly valid url.